# ASP.NET 3.5 with Entity Framework already in use. Best way to call a sproc?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I have a small application that uses Entity Framework to expose information to an oData service.  I need to allow my web server to call a SQL sproc for auditing purposes.

What technology should I use to keep the app "clean"?

- Should I follow [these](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/implement-select-stored-procedures-that-return-miscellaneous-data-in-ctp2-of-ef-designer/) directions for EF3.5?
- Should I use ADO.NET?
- Linq2SQL?
- Should I upgrade to .NET 4 so I can take advantage of the better EF?

What makes the most sense from a supportability perspective?

Answer (score 1):

This is subjective, but I'd go for EF4.

Answer (score 1):

Well the only real difference between ADO.NET/L2SQL/EF is that EF4 allows mapping of stored procedures to **complex types**.

What this means is you can map the result of a stored proc directly to a POCO, and align it with your domain model.

This is not possible with ADO.NET / L2SQL, and for that reason alone i'd also recommend EF4.

Answer (score 0):

i would also recommend EF4 because there are so many things in EF4 that actually works. Also there has been lot of improvements in sql generation for EF4.